# como mostrar una lista de varios objetos en c++

Tags: c++, poo

lo que pasa es que haciendo un ejercicio de practica, me piden mostrar todos los prestamos de libros realizados por un estudiante, ya en mi planificación, intente hacer una lista donde se guarda la info del préstamo pero, indagando encontré que una excepción a mi código es que puede que el estudiante haya hecho 2 o mas prestamos por lo que solo una lista de la información del préstamo no es suficiente ya que puede haber mas, por lo tanto, dejo mi código y espero sus recomendaciones:

codigo en el cpp:

```
list<Prestamo*> * Biblioteca::devolverPrestamos(Prestamo * prestamo){
    list<Prestamo*> * nuevoPrestamo = new list<Prestamo *>();
    list<Prestamo*>::iterator it = this->muchosPrestamos->begin();
    Prestamo * prest;
    for(;it!=this->muchosPrestamos->end();it++){
        prest=*it;
        if(prest->GetUnEstudiante()->GetCodigo()==prestamo->GetUnEstudiante()->GetCodigo()){
            nuevoPrestamo->push_back(prest);
        }
    }
    return nuevoPrestamo;
}
```

codimo en el main:

```
Prestamo * prestamo4 = new Prestamo("22 de septiembre del 2025", est, lib);
biblioteca1->addPrestamo(prestamo4);
```

Comment: Bienvenido. ¿Puedes ser más claro? ¿Cuál es el resultado esperado? ¿En qué falla?

Comment: el resultado esperado es mostrar la informacion de todos los prestamos, cada prestamo es un objeto, por lo que debo devolver una lista de todos estos, fecha del prestamo, estudiante y libro.

Comment: segun mi codigo, devuelvo un solo objeto tipo prestamo

Comment: no sabemos cómo es`Prestamo` ni donde se encuentra la lista de préstamos. De la misma forma tampoco sabemos cómo identificar al usuario del préstamo ni si hay una lista de usuarios ... a la hora de elaborar una pregunta ponte en la piel de alguien que desconoce totalmente tu ejercicio .. dado que es a esa persona a la que va dirigida tu pregunta, todo lo que creas que es necesario para que esa persona entienda tu situación es lo mismo que necesitaremos nosotros para entenderte

Answer (score 0):

En [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b), cuando quieres mostrar información, lo habitual es sobrecargar el operador de escritura en flujo de datos de salida: `std::ostream &operator<<`.

Así que, suponiendo que tenemos:

1. Una colección de `Estudiante`s:

   ```
   struct Estudiante { string nombre; /* otras cosas */ };
   map<int, Estudiante> estudiantes;
   ```
2. Una colección de `Libro`s:

   ```
   struct Libro { string nombre; /* otras cosas */ };
   map<int, Libro> libros;
   ```
3. Un objeto `Prestamo`:

   ```
   struct Prestamo { int idLibro, idEstudiante; /* otras cosas */ };
   ```

Escribimos las sobrecargas:

```
std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &o, const Estudiante &e)
{
    return o << e.nombre;
}

std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &o, const Libro &l)
{
    return o << l.nombre;
}

std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &o, const Prestamo &p)
{
    return o << "\"" << libros[p.idLibro] << "\" prestado a: \"" << estudiantes[p.idEstudiante] << "\"";// << ' ' << p.fecha;
}
```

Con esto nos podemos permitir escribir este código:

```
std::list<Prestamo> prestamos
{
//  id libro    id estudiante
    {42,        111},
    {342391,    123},
    {12345678,  16431834},
    {1193046,   288394},
    {42,        288394},
    {342391,    111},
    {12345678,  123},
    {1193046,   16431834},
    {42,        16431834},
    {342391,    288394},
    {12345678,  111},
    {1193046,   123},
    {42,        123},
    {342391,    16431834},
    {12345678,  288394},
    {1193046,   111},
};

for (const auto &p : prestamos)
    std::cout << p << '\n';
```

Puedes ver el código funcionando en <kbd>[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##pVTbbtswDH22v4LIgPSCrIljr0sTI0C3duhDMRTY47oHxlZcAbakSXYxIMhX9RP2YRklXzN0D9tiILbJw0MeknKi1NskR5EdDm@4SPIqZRBzaUrNsFj7vY0sXGRDS4Fq@JpzU659vzIEA4EFMwoTBqZMV75P0VVSwq0pq5SjKBnsrGe5rGlByGKj2Qqm5yBLjQYSaej/fAr7le@AlC3mopwMONbAumfj73xvFwTBxPN2o@sMFS8lpBy@yMrgaL@fWPc8dO47pgsmWMbzVMIDqkp2kNmPLW4wxQnBPj5xkzLxTGkRbilJzr5XvEXOF4vwKrK4z7ipEilSqeFayULlcisJ5O974fd8o@W/a3bha8jtrVY62wQze9n89wifKpFiwn@@iFYHaY3eXb63/ptKsL4D1rpw8jTBeUIpaXw5wo3GTArahYR1zajxFn2bwwdpjBQWfcezzJAAoEE@IyA80ai1JUmwwFZ7K/5B05ywsPpJDfDUyZnQQz/LP7Sh7kOzjjCWimkspY7j098cEwoT5mjDxuyMWgX006ystAAJcQzsoum7v/979nqM4/w14vx/iLsWjdVr3KPH0cjlcAvwVV00PfzWOEG5eNpmXEKDHZwNF9B3po0araZT@3hCF93UxZYlT@jqt3MqkItTW43nirbnO27rXDcZC1pHjxDeLprT0aLzZxfH24XRPLyis0j7Uxv6xQsuozBYhFFjD67CWUQbVh@n2ui4hoaOruUf0HUZWqbjBHVdR6aWbZhhQNjl6AjbFDVX@9YVdSyoIzqi77hqdrva3pY@GKf1/LEq7exh2ff1jOJc4xNZlW4@blaP4sTGNtsxo2kdDr8A)</kbd>.

Answer (score 0):

Seguramente el problema se encuentra en tu diseño, y por como yo lo veo, la lógica de los préstamos, se puede diseñar de la siguiente forma:

Creamos la clase libro, este es el objeto que se va a prestar.

```
class Libro{
    std::string titulo_;
    std::string autor_;
    // algunos metodos . . .
};
```

Creamos la clase estudiante, esta es la entidad que solicitara el préstamo.

```
class Estudiante{
    std::string nombre_;
    std::string dni_;
    // algunos metodos . . 
};
```

**NOTA:** las clases libro y estudiante no están relacionadas porque en un préstamo estas dos entidades no tienen por qué conocerse el uno al otro.

Creamos la clase préstamo, esta si tiene una relación con la clase libro, pues para registrar un préstamo debe conocer cuál es el objeto en cuestión que se está prestando.

```
class Prestamo{
    std::list<Libro> libro_; //--> un prestamo puede tener mas de un articulo
    std::string fechaPrestamo_;
    std::string fechaDevolucion_;
    // algunos metodos . . .
};
```

Finalmente, creamos la clase titular que relaciona al estudiante con el préstamo, porque como sabemos, cuando se solicita un préstamo, este queda a nombre de alguien y ese alguien es el titular del préstamo.

```
class Titular{
    Estudiante estudiante_; //--> titular de el o los prestamos
    std::list<Prestamo> prestamos_; //--> un titular puede realizar mas de un prestamo
    //  algunos metodos . . .
};
```

Teóricamente si desarrollas el ejercicio bajo este diseño de clases estarías dando solución al problema planteado, además, ten en cuenta que se puede seguir expandiendo, porque como ya tenemos una clase titular es posible tener una list de titulares manejando así una coleccion de varios titulares en lugar de manejar solo uno.